# Is linux fork insecure

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, exec, fork

I was reading this [article](http://www.bottomupcs.com/fork_and_exec.html)

It says that the fork create a copy of itself and `fork` man also says so

> . The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child

**Does this mean child process can read all my process memory state  ?**

**Can child process dump the entire parent memory state and it can be analysed to extract parent variable and its value. ?**

But the article also says that two process cannot ready each other data.
So i am confused ?

Comment: You are probably confused, but this is normal. Fork is actually difficult to understand (like [multiverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) are...). So take time to read several times several explanations about `fork`. You'll need hours to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the child process can read *a pristine copy* of all of the parent process state (but when writing, only its own address space is affected) just after a [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). However, most of the time, the child would eventually use [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) to start a new program, and that would "clear" and replace the copy of the original parent's address space (by a fresh address space). Notice that `execve`  and [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (see also [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29) in [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)...) are the common ways to change the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) of some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (and how the kernel handles [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault)).

The kernel uses (and sets up the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) for) lazy [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) machinery to make the child's address space a copy of the parent's one, so `fork` is quite efficient in practice.

Read also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), then type the follow commands:

```
cat /proc/self/maps
cat /proc/$$/maps
sudo cat /proc/1/maps
```

and understand what is happening

Read also the wikipage on [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), and the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.

There is no insecurity, because if the child is changing some data (e.g. a variable, a heap or stack location, ...) it does not affect the parent process.

If the program doing the fork is keeping some password in some virtual memory location, the child process would be able to read that location as long as it is executing the same program. Once the child did a successful `execve`  (which is the common situation, and what any shell is doing) the previous address space is gone and replaced by a new one, described in the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable of that `exec`-ed program.

There is no "lie" or "insecurity" in that Unix model. But contrarily to several other operating systems, Unix & POSIX have two separate [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for creating a new process (`fork`) and executing a new program (`execve`). Other systems might have some single [spawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28computing%29) operation mixing the two abilities. [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) is often implemented by a mixture of `fork` & `execve` (and so are [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) & [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), also using [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) & `/bin/sh`....).

The advantage of that Unix approach (having separated `fork` & `execve`) is that after the `fork`  and before the `execve` in the child you can do a lot of useful things (e.g. closing useless file descriptors, ...). Operating Systems not separating the two features may need to have a quite complex spawning primitive.

There are rare occasions where a `fork` is *not* followed by some `execve`. Some [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) implementations might do that, and you might also do that. But then you know that you are able to read all the parent's address space thru your own copy - so what you felt was an insecurity is becoming a *useful feature*. In the old days you had the obsolete [vfork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) which blocked the parents. There is not need to use it today; actually, `fork` is often implemented thru [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) which you should not use directly in practice (see [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)...) but only thru [POSIX pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). But thinking of `fork` as a magical cloner of your process might help.

When coding (even in C) don't forget to test against failure of `fork`  and of `execve`. See [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

PS. the `fork` syscall is as difficult to understand as the [multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) idea. Both are "forking" the time!

Comment: "There is no insecurity, because if the child is changing some data". so if i have a password stored in a variable of parent then i fork the child then child can extract that variable value somehow as child process can read a pristine copy...and also the statement " two process cannot ready each other data" is a lie

Comment: @user2410148 a fork just causes a process to duplicate. It's still the exact same program. If your program has code for extracting passwords from itself, you don't need a fork to run that code, and the fork doesn't help that functionality in any way.

Comment: *" two process cannot ready each other data" is a lie* -- I suggest being very careful with the word "lie"; it implies deliberate deceit, which I don't think is what you meant. In fact two processes generally *can't* read each other's data. After `fork()`, the new process's data happens to be a copy of the parent process's data. (`fork`'s copy-on-write semantics means that no physical copy is usually necessary.)

Comment: careful with the word "lie"...not the actual intention.. just getting emotional

Answer (score 2):

When you call [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), the new process will get access to the **copy of the parent process memory** (i.e. variables, file descriptors etc).

This is in contrast with threads, where all threads share the same memory space, i.e. variable modified in one thread will get a new value in all other threads.

So if, **after forking**, parent process modifies memory, the child process will not see that change - because the memory has been copied, the child process' memory would not get altered.

Comment: as memtioned in title i am more looking at it from security perspective...so if i have a password stored in a variable of parent then the child can extract that variable value somehow...and also the statement " two process cannot ready each other data" is a lie

Comment: If you want new process to be more independent, you might take a look at `exec-*` family of funcitons (POSIX) - so you can fork, and then immediately replace the fork process (you can do it, since newly forked process is controlled by you); Or possibly have a look at `popen()` as well.